# How to store the output of `pwd` along with regular commands in history?

Tags: bash, history

I want to know how I can include the current working directory (output of `pwd`) to the commands stored in `.bash_history` file.

I want this because sometimes same command is executed from different directories. It's really helpful to know from which directory a particular instance of a command was executed.

Comment: How about `pwd >> ~/.bash_history`?

Comment: You mean making an alias of the what you are saying? Yes.

Comment: Umm.. Creating an alias of pwd >> ~/.bash_history as pwd does send the full path to the ~/.bash_history but I would like to retain the output on the terminal also. How can I do that?

Comment: this does it : pwd && pwd >> ~/.bash_history
thanks.

Comment: alias pwd='pwd | tee -a ~/.bash_history'

Comment: I wouldn't recommend  writing to `~/.bash_history` file.  Use a separate one and write both the command and its output to the file. See the linked question for variety of ways of doing that.

Comment: @BajarangSutar I've edited your question. Check if it is what you wanted. Your original question was very unclear

Answer (score 0):

Add this command to your .bash_rc:

```
alias pwd='pwd | tee -a ~/.bash_history'
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have suggested, writing your current directory to your `.bash_history` can get you back to it.

But on the fly, see if *pushing the current directory on to the stack* and *poping back to it later* might be what you need.

```
 pushd . 
 cd /else/where/
 popd
```

you can also push as many directories. Poping them one at a time will revert the working directory back in the pushed order.

- `pushd .` saves the current directory (don't forget the dot `.`),
- `cd` changes working directory,
- `popd` brings you back to the last pushed (saved) directory.

These commands will also show you the folder you have saved in their respective order every time you push or pop.
and when entering the command `history`, you will be able to track back the changes made in each directory afterwards.